# laravel Illegal offset type

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code in the controller

```
  $order = Order::with(['media','contact'])
        ->get();
```

and this is my code in the view and it work fine

```
 <label> {{__($order['details'])}} </label>
```

but if I change the attribute to timestamp attribute like 'created_at' , 'updated_at'  I got this error

```
Illegal offset type
```

note that: the code in the view is inside foreach

Comment: We need to see more code here. This line doesn't seems to throw the error you got

Comment: Why are you using array access, to access a model object? Can you provide your for loop please?

Comment: Nvm, somehow did not realize laravel let you do either

Comment: Note: In your current code, `$order` is a `Collection`; `->get()` **returns multiple `Order` objects**. If you're not already, you need to loop them, like `@foreach($orders as $order)`, and prefer to use `object` syntax: `$order->details` instead of `array` syntax `$order['details']` (although both are allowed, objects is preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are putting the output into the translation function, and the output of those timestamps is a carbon instance.

```
>>> __($u['created_at'])
PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php on line 111
PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/NamespacedItemResolver.php on line 25
PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/NamespacedItemResolver.php on line 43
PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php on line 330
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php on line 117
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php on line 117
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1451606400 {#4467
     date: 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00),
   }
```

But no issue here.

```
>>> $u['created_at']
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1451606400 {#4465
     date: 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>>
```